# Flutter using agora: How can I limit the number of speakers to eight inside one room

Tags: flutter, dart, real-time, provider, agora.io

- I'm trying to create a room with users that can speak in a mic in this room using agora
- but I just need to limit number of users to be eight, could someone inform me how to implement this

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using `agora_rtm`. You can check how many members are in the call, and if there are 8 already in there, don't let them join.